# How to build [11-20] and [10-10] surfaces of hexagonal 2H, 1T and 1T’ monolayers?

Tags: density-functional-theory, surfaces

I couldn’t find any software. Does anyone have any free software suggestions. I tried to do it with vesta but couldn’t figure out and for polytypes other than the 2H there are not any sources. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just as a heads up, there is some ongoing discussion about limiting the participation of unregistered users on the site: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317/does-the-matter-modeling-community-want-to-ban-unregistered-users-from-asking-qu. If you register your account, you won't have to worry if any limits are put in place for unregistered accounts.

Comment: I will suggest you to generate structure using ovito. You can also check ASE build mx2 https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/surface.html#ase.build.mx2

Comment: @pranavkumar since the user is unregistered, the question will probably get closed according to the new policy unless people are willing to write answers, so if you think you can write an answer and save this question, please go ahead!

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.